# Is running a local CircleCI pipeline beneficial?

Tags: git, localhost, pipeline, pull-request, circleci

When a PR is created the CircleCI cloud is running and giving the results, when errors are occurred, have to fix them and keep on create PRs and do fixes based on results until it get passed. In such a case, is it beneficial to run CircleCI locally and make sure it works before pushing for a PR to the main repo ?

Answer (score 1):

If the build server isn't able to service your build request immediately, it makes sense. For example, it may be currently building someone else's commit, and therefore your commit request is in a queue. In such a case, your turnaround may be quicker with a local build.

Another reason is if the server is running on aging hardware, or if the server is a virtual machine running on an oversubscribed host. Your local machine may have more resources in those circumstances, and therefore build the codebase more quickly.

I recommend always checking the CircleCI status anyway. If you rely on the build results coming from the builds on your own computer, you risk being affected by the ["Works on My Machine" problem](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/).